# How to customize ion text area in ionic?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, textarea

I would like ask for some assistance regarding on how to use `ion-textarea`. I am new in **Ionic** and experiencing a lot of new things in using this. Please refer to the image below on how I will fix this issue. Instead of showing scrollbar in the right side. The text was shown outside the text area. Hope you can help me. Thank you

[image]

Here's my code I used:

```
<ion-col size-md = "12">
    <ion-textarea class = "italic" rows="10" cols="5" maxlength = "200" placeholder="Please provide additional comments here..."  [(ngModel)]="postFeedback.explanation"></ion-textarea>
 </ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/textarea) for this or any future questions regarding the natural behavior of ionic.
To answer your question: try using autoGrow = "true"  as follows :

```
<ion-col size-md = "12">
    <ion-textarea class = "italic" rows="10" cols="5" autoGrow="true" maxlength = "200" placeholder="Please provide additional comments here..."  [(ngModel)]="postFeedback.explanation"></ion-textarea>
 </ion-col>
```